# Let's congratulate Walt for achieving a milestone of 100k

Tags: discussion

Walt is a resourceful and valued contributor to our community here.  He is always polite, thoughtful and helpful to all users.

He has earned the recognition and respect of the community for his efforts and has now achieved the milestone of 100k reputation.

[image: Walt]

Please join me in congratulating Walt for his impressive contribution to the community!

<sub>Note: Due to Identification low-quality post purging he lost that spot for now but we are hopeful he will get it back again.</sub>

Comment: Congratulations to lord almighty.

Comment: Congratulations Walt!  You simply amaze me with your research talents!  We are extremely fortunate to have you in our community.  Your contributions here are a paragon that everyone should strive to reproduce :)

Comment: Congrats Walt...you're running away with this.

Comment: Indeed - congratulations Walt

Comment: yay!  congrats @walt

Comment: Congrats, Walt! I know I'm new here, but you, as have many, have been so helpful and nice! Thank you! :)

Comment: @Walt Enjoy your swag pack from SE! :-D

Comment: WowoWoWoWow!!!!

Comment: Dude answers all the obscure stuff like a champ.  He's either got mad Googling skillz or he's got the biggest movie collection on the planet.  WTG, Walt!

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Competition! I mean... Congratulations! :)

Comment: If I live to be 500 years old, I might get half-way there.

Comment: Congrats Walt... Hail hydra ;)

Comment: Well earned. Good job!

Comment: Congrats to the true internet movie database! :D

Comment: congrats and now aim for 500k

Comment: I'm a little late to the party but yes, congratulations! We're all appreciative of your contributions to our community. When I see an answer from you I always know it will be accurate, helpful, and thorough. Your comments and advice to newbies (including me a year ago!) strike just the right tone.

Comment: Thanks everyone (and AJ for the post), you're very very kind.

Answer (score 2):

I'm very sorry to see that Walt has now lost his impressive 6-figure rep score, and is back down to 90k. Now that most of his answers are locked and unable to be voted on, who knows if he'll ever even be able to get back to 100k again.

> *raises glass* **Cheers for the six-digit-rep Walt-that-Was!**

Just one of the sad consequences of [the death of ID on this site](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4146/27759).

Comment: I am also feeling bad for @Walt and other users, but we already knew there will certainly be reputation loss during this ID cleanup. Even though, ID was the main thing that Walt has expertise in, we have also seen his prowess in other tags as well (you can see he already has silver in [tag:plot-explanation]). I hope and am sure that he will get back to six digits with his expertise in other area as well. :)

Comment: This post lack to address that Walt’s answer always got love (ID or not) because of there quality. There are still loads of great answer which can attract more votes and many he can make in future and reach 100k again.