# My posts disappeared from the site

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I like to drop by our site from time to time but I am not a very frequent user, so I'm not sure when this happened

I remember I had 3 more identification questions on the site, each had upvotes, comments and answers, and in one of then I think I had accepted the answer as well

To be specific, one question was about a WWE episode identification, one was about a leprachaun movie (called Land of the Small or something?) and one was about a Rowan Atkinson sketch identification (turned out to be Blackadder's Christmas episode)

A few weeks ago I noticed they were gone without a trace, I have not been keeping track of reputation so I'm not sure how it was affected, but the questions definitely are not in my asked-questions list

What happened to my questions? Is there any way I can find out about them using any features of the website available to general users, or are only mods allowed to view it? Could someone look into this please?

Answer (score 5):

At the beginning of 2018 the site went through a [scope adjustment that finally retired identification questions](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4087/49). As part of that there also was a cleanup phase of the existing baggage of old questions that resulted in all of them getting closed and historically locked, as well as [deleted unless they had a score of >4 and an answer of >2](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4138/49). The majority of the questions you're after got cleaned up in this process. Some of the to be deleted questions were also migrated to Science Fiction & Fantasy if appropriate, which actually was the case for [one of your questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180718/23386).

You only lost reputation from the ones that had a score <3, which was the case for half of these, so you should have lost about 18 rep from this.

You actually still *can* view the posts' pages, since they're your own, but there is no easy way for you to get links to these questions unless you have at least 10,000 reputation, in which case you can search for `user:4763 is:question deleted:yes` (or even without the user since you can only search for your own deleted posts anyway). There is, however, a [feature request on Meta Stack Exchange for allowing normal users to see their deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/162011), it was declined though.

But since you ask nicely and there are not millions of them, I can list them here for you:

- https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/32448/49
- https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/36933/49
- https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/39115/49
- https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/60665/49
- https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/64053/49