# What power structures are in place here? Is this site democratic?

Tags: discussion, identify

I thought the moderation here is not akin to an authoritarian regime but democratic, based on consensus and therefore reflects the will of the users.

But judging from these facts it appears to be the other way round:

> now the "consensus" on the original "Check in" post is solidly pro-ID
> and the ban announcement is the [most unpopular post ever](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A..-15) while [the
> most popular](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3A70..) are pro-ID, but by then the ban was already a *fait
> accompli*.
> source: https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4751/69311

So please explain the real power structure here.
On what grounds are decisions taken here by the few against popular demand of the many?
How is this democratic?

Answer (score 3):

SE never claimed to be a democracy, in fact **it very much isn't**, at least not in the rather simplistic and direct interpretation of the term you seem to employ here. You seem to imply that there is a very clear black-and-white distinction between "the majority" (whoever that is) voting for every single decision and a dictatorship where everything is subject to the whims of the moderators and everything is either one or the other. That is not even *remotely* how the real world or real democracies work, let alone an SE site.

In the same way scope decisions aren't made based on simple yes/no polls, this is explained in more detail in [this related meta discussion on consensus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177550/162011) as well as [this discussion on polls](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233908/162011) (and [this ages old blog post about "popularity"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/01/31/the-trouble-with-popularity/) touches on the subject a bit, too). And in the case you bring up and seem to be mostly concerned about, an **informed decision** was made by the moderators based on **years of history and a trend in site development**, which culminated in a **reasoned discussion about the issue** that went for a month and where noone felt the need to explain why those questions should be retained, be that with an answer let alone a downvote. From this a **consensus became apparent**.

However, people don't react well to supposedly having something taken away from them, especially if you link every poor user trying to ask such a question to that meta discussion. Voting something up or down is quite a bit easier than actually caring, thinking and arguing why certain questions are good or bad for the site as a whole (rather than for you right now needing to know what on earth that thing with that guy was that you saw for 5 minutes on TV last year). Which is precisely the reason sites aren't governed by polls rather than discussions.

The rather unrelated post you cite falls into the same trap of basically calling everything that has a lot of upvotes a "consensus" based on a **purely poll-oriented way of site governing**, where you basically change site-scope 180° every other month because people didn't appreciate the things changed last month so much. You don't actually need human moderators for that, though. A robot could do that as well as it can draw "art" or "answer" your questions nowadays. ;-)